# How to hide the empty TextBlock?

Tags: wpf

In the XAML provided below, I don't have the value for Phone sometimes. When that happens, the value is missing, but the `TextBlock` is still occupying the space in the panel. I want to hide empty `TextBlock`s from taking space in the `StackPanel`.

Here's the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Phone}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528525/wpf-how-to-make-empty-textblock-not-to-occupy-space), but the accepted answer doesn't work for me:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Phone}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere, or is the accepted answer wrong? What should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is a phone property String.Empty or Null when it is created or deleted?

Comment: It's null. The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You probably need to use:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

or maybe both:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This has the curious effect of hiding every single one of my labels, including the text to the right of checkboxes. Not good :)

Comment: @RomanStarkov Move the `<Style>` to a <Resources>` element that has a more appropriate scope for your labels (perhaps the enclosing `<StackPanel>`) or use `x:Key` so only named styles are applied.

Answer (score 46):

Instead of introducing a style just for this, for this sort of thing I tend to prefer using a converter that will handle a null or empty string.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}"
           Visibility="{Binding Foo, 
                        Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Where `StringToVisibilityConverter` is defined like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(Visibility))]
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually use `Converter`s to convert the data to make it more user-friendly to the end user, but your code works just fine. Still, I prefer the styles for my scenario. Thanks for an answer either way!

Comment: Generally I agree with that but look at the ONE built in converter that WPF ships: BooleanToVisibilityConverter. It does the exact thing you are doing but with boolean values

Comment: +1 Always nice to condense two triggers that perform the same function into one.

Comment: You probably meant `Visibility=...` instead of `Text=...`. I've taken the liberty to change that.

Comment: This is the cleanest and most straightforward solution, better than a verbose style IMHO. But with two small comments: in many cases, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` might be more desirable. Second, use `Visibility="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringValidConverter}}"` to avoid a direct, repeated reference to the bound value.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a `DataTrigger`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```