# WPF: How to hide the empty Hyperlink?

Tags: wpf, styles

In [the previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573864/wpf-how-to-hide-the-empty-textblock), I have asked how to hide an empty `TextBlock`, so that it doesn't take space in the panel. I have a new challenge now. How am I supposed to hide an empty `Hyperlink`:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Hyperlink 
      NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Email}"
      RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
  </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

This is what made the hiding possible in the previous question:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Providing this style on first `TextBlock` won't work because the `Text` property is not set. Providing style on `Hyperlink` doesn't hide the parent `TextBlock` and same happens if I try to hide the `TextBlock` inside the `Hyperlink`.

I am certain that my style needs to be applied on the `Hyperlink`, but the trigger inside should target the `Visibility` property of the 'Hyperlink`'s parent`TextBlock`. What is the style supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573864/wpf-how-to-hide-the-empty-textblock) provided by [Foovanadil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206625/foovanadil) that solves the similar issue by implementing *visibility converter* works the best in my opinion. It is the easiest to implement and can be reused whenever needed.

The converter should be implemented like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                            CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                             CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

}

And used like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Visibility converter -->
    <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibleConv" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Something, Converter={StaticResource visibleConv}}">
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Something}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Something}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

All credits go to the original solution provider: [Foovanadil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206625/foovanadil)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `DataTrigger` on the top level `TextBlock` to check whether the bound property is an empty string:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Email}" Value="">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Also you can try binding to the child hyperlink's `NavigationUri` property:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Inlines
[0].NavigateUri}" Value="">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Comment: There's a problem. There is more than one `Hyperlink` and I'd prefer not to have multiple styles, i.e. in your answer, the trigger is bound to a specific value - Email, where I want to have it bound to `Hyperlink`'s `NavigateUri`. This way, if `NavigateUri` gets a value, any kind of value, the text block will be shown, otherwise collapsed. Can you show me how to reach the `Visibility` property of the parent `TextBlock` from `Hyperlink`'s style?

Comment: Hey Pavlo, have you tried your code? I have absolutely no idea why, but now the style doesn't work! The value the hyperlink is binded to is of type `Uri`. If the `NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Email}"` value is `null` it doesn't show the `TextBlock`, but if it isn't, it doesn't show it as well. Also, I changed value of `DataTrigger` to `{x:Null}` becuase for empty string it ALWAYS shows the `TextBlock`

Comment: Could it be because the `NavigateUri` gets the value after the trigger has been set and the value checked?

Comment: @Boris - When I posted my answer I made a typo in the code sample - I wrote `NavigationUri` instead of `NavigateUri` in the binding. Please check this.

Comment: Nah, I found that error myself. It's not that. You see, the `TextBlock` does get hidden for every single situation, no matter what `NavigateUri` gets. So, the binding mechanism works, it just doesn't make the difference in regard to the `NavigateUri` value. Could it be because the NavigateUri gets the value after the trigger has been set and the value checked?

Comment: I fond an error in the debugger output: "System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Object') from 'Inlines' (type 'InlineCollection'). BindingExpression:Path=Inlines[0].NavigateUri; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."