# Datatrigger on empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How can a DataTrigger change the visibility of stackpanel, based on a binded string?
I have the following Xaml

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            Background="#FF7a7a7a">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchText}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    Content....
   </StackPanel>
```

I Know that `SearchText` gets updates and binds properly outside the `StackPanel`

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: When I bind to a `TextBox`Text property it works. Do you know what your property is returning?

Comment: My `SearchText` property is a `String` type

Comment: Yes, but is it returning any value or is it returning `null`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573864/how-to-hide-the-empty-textblock?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchText}" Value="">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

will work for empty string (`""`), however it will not work for `null`.

Add another `DataTrigger` for the null case:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchText}" Value="{x:Null}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: You can combine both triggers into one if you add the following as part of the binding expression `TargetNullValue=''`

Answer (score 15):

Correct using String.Empty in XAML:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchText}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird as it might sound, the code below works for me:

```
<StackPanel Background="#FF7a7a7a">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBlock}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBlock" Text="" Width="100" Height="30"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Can you tell the value your Property is sending?

Comment: The my string was not initialized having a value of null, therefor it seemed to not work.

Comment: Yeah, @HighCore was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<StackPanel.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBoundPropertyName}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </StackPanel.Style>
```