# uwp - hide textblock if text is empty or null

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to hide a textblock with a binding if the content is null or empty. If found many solutions but most in WPF like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573864/how-to-hide-the-empty-textblock).

But there isn't style triggers in UWP. Is there a way to achieve the same result ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards

Comment: Visibility binding with converter

Comment: Thank you ! I though there was another solution other than Converters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom converter like this:

```
public sealed class StringIsNullOrWhiteSpaceToVisibilityInvertedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I though there was another solution other than Converters.

Comment: @ArthurCPPCLI a solution without converters would involve code behind and a lot less reusable